# index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I have the following function which produces an out of bounds error:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,4].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder , OneHotEncoder

labelencoder_x = LabelEncoder()
x[:,3] = labelencoder_x.fit_transform(x[:,3])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
x = onehotencoder.fit_transform(x).toarray()
x = x[:,1:]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor  = LinearRegression()
regressor  = regressor.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred  = regressor.predict(x_test)


import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

x = np.append(arr = np.ones((50,1)).astype(int) , values = x , axis = 1)
x_opt = x[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
regressor_ols = sm.OLS(endog= y , exog = x_opt).fit()
regressor_ols.summary()
x_opt = x[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
regressor_ols = sm.OLS(endog= y , exog = x_opt).fit()'''
```

**The full error displayed is :**

```
x_opt = x[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]

Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "<ipython-input-45-62cb7e2f326e>", line 1, in <module>

    x_opt = x[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]


IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5
```

How can i solve this error ?

Comment: Look at `x.shape`.  The error indicates it has 5 columns (axis 1 with size 5).  If so, why are you trying to index it with 6 values, including 5.

Comment: Creating a [mcve] for your question may have highlighted the problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

Well an array with a size of 5 has it's last index as 4.

An array always starts at index 0 and not 1.

Comment: Thank you  but why is there is occurence of size error here ? I have not fixed the size of array in the code.